# Bootstrapping elements of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, quantile, percentile

I have a procedure that takes data and creates a square matrix *M*, where the elements of *M* correspond to certain features of the data. I wish to get a confidence interval for each element of the matrix to measure the uncertainty around each feature that I'm estimating. To do this, I want to bootstrap, so I initialize a list in R, resample my data, and store the resulting matrices in the list. How can I then estimate the 95% confidence interval for each element?

For example, say my original matrix *M* is 10 by 10, and the list of bootstrapped matrices is

```
mylist <- list()
for(i in 1:1000){
    boot_matrices[[i]] <- matrix(rnorm(10*10, mean=0, sd=1), nrow=10, ncol=10)
}
```

I wish to calculate a confidence interval around each (i,j) element in *M*, where i=1...10 and j=1...10 by using the 1000 bootstrap matrices. In this toy example, I know the parametric distribution of each (i,j) element, and I'd expect the 95% confidence interval for each element to be around (-1.96, 1.96). However, in my real data, I don't know as much, and I don't want to assume as much (hence, using bootstrap). Is there a way to automatically calculate confidence intervals around each matrix element in this case?

Comment: Are you asking for a confidence interval around the mean of these indexed elements or a prediction interval?

Comment: @42- I'm not sure a prediction interval makes much sense in a bootstrap context. The standard deviation (or confidence interval of the mean) of the bootstrap distribution will correspond to the standard deviation (or confidence interval of the mean) of the (unknown) target distribution (assuming convergence of the bootstrap dist to the target dist).

Comment: In this case there are two possible "standard deviations": 1) the standard deviation of the individual elements obtained at the same index of the matrices (this often being used to construct a prediction interval that might hold 95% of the elements under conditions of normality) and 2) the standard error of the estimated mean which is used to construct a 95% confidence interval for the mean. (It wasn't clear that Florian understood the difference since to my reading his request was imprecise or at least ambiguous.)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

Create `nBS` bootstrap `10x10` matrices (I'm using `set.seed(...)` to ensure reproducibility of sample data). Resulting matrices are stored in a `list`.

```
# List of bootstrap matrices
nBS <- 1000;
set.seed(2017);
lst <- lapply(1:nBS, function(x) 
    matrix(rnorm(10 * 10, mean = 0, sd = 1), nrow = 10, ncol = 10));
```

Calculate the mean and standard deviation for every matrix element (i,j) across all bootstrap samples:

```
# Calculate mean and sd of every matrix element (i,j)
mat.mean <- apply(simplify2array(lst), c(1, 2), mean);
mat.sd <- apply(simplify2array(lst), c(1, 2), sd);
```

Calculate 95% confidence interval as `mean +- 1.96 * sem`:

```
# Calculate lower and upper 95% confidence interval
mat.lowerCI <- mat.mean - 1.96 * mat.sd / sqrt(nBS);
mat.upperCI <- mat.mean + 1.96 * mat.sd / sqrt(nBS);
```

Show `mat.mean`:

```
mat.mean;
             [,1]         [,2]          [,3]         [,4]         [,5]
[1,] -0.011862801 -0.017872385 -2.059780e-02 -0.056602452 -0.077408704
[2,]  0.083863805 -0.057467756 -7.920189e-03  0.001923072 -0.010616517
[3,] -0.021193913 -0.021594100 -3.069827e-03  0.082500345 -0.015010818
[4,] -0.001063529 -0.028606045  6.366336e-02  0.021871973  0.014491280
[5,] -0.042912905 -0.020031203  7.075698e-03  0.032309070  0.051875125
[6,] -0.028336190 -0.055650895 -1.119998e-02 -0.030252861 -0.008670326
[7,]  0.006555878 -0.008686383 -1.928690e-02 -0.027290181 -0.002037219
[8,]  0.001513634 -0.057669094 -6.025466e-03  0.028409560  0.052159330
[9,]  0.044741065 -0.026265301  3.915427e-02 -0.011599341  0.006817949
[10,]  0.035356686 -0.039949595 -5.468612e-05  0.007272050  0.013150241
[,6]          [,7]         [,8]         [,9]         [,10]
[1,]  0.054420568  0.0050127337 -0.046358349 -0.029833662 -0.0525282034
[2,] -0.033703118 -0.0623761140 -0.029511715 -0.048816905 -0.0189984349
[3,] -0.013218223 -0.0278959480 -0.036351073  0.028833428 -0.0001538902
[4,]  0.029236408 -0.0046022995  0.019077031  0.069887669 -0.0283910941
[5,] -0.035474785  0.0372263523  0.021329823  0.006252149  0.0395028012
[6,]  0.008978299  0.0266740599 -0.006252266 -0.005793750  0.0072594645
[7,]  0.092958577  0.0047135528  0.019320387  0.011766436 -0.0021045223
[8,]  0.014867452 -0.0001325218  0.014760887 -0.027671024  0.0610503856
[9,] -0.031151561  0.0373095832  0.016197685 -0.050206244 -0.0561044648
[10,]  0.059817479 -0.0669659941  0.020218135 -0.039548025  0.0115156843
```

Lower and upper 95% confidence intervals are given in `mat.lowerCI` and `mat.upperCI`.